# Log which system executables have been used

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, executable, alpine-linux

I have an Ubuntu-based Dockerfile and I'd like to change it to be based on a minimal Debian or maybe even Alpine.
The problem is that I'm relying on a lot of system executables that came preinstalled and I don't know which ones. Now in order to write a new Dockerfule based on Alpine I first need to find out which programs are being used and then I need to find out the name of the package that provides it on Alpine.
Is there an easy way to simply log which system executables will be used by the Docker container?
I was thinking of maybe moving everything found in PATH to a new directory and then creating bash scripts that sort of act as a proxy, logging the executable name and then calling the real executable. But would that be safe/reliable or even possible?

Comment: Even if you find a way to log everything, how are you certain that **all** possible calls to external executables are made when you run the containerized application? To ensure you catch all cases, I believe you would have to analyze the application's code.

Comment: I think in my case it would actually catch all cases, but even if it woulndn't, it would already help a lot get 95% of the calls. Analyzing the application's code would be incredibly time consuming because of it's size.

Answer (score 3):

You could use ftrace for this and log each call to exec.
On Ubuntu you can download the utility `trace-cmd`:

```
apt install trace-cmd
```

Then look for the exec events (should be `sched_process_exec`, check with `trace-cmd list | grep exec` if it doesn't work for you). You need to run it with root permissions.

```
sudo trace-cmd record -e "sched_process_exec" your_program
trace-cmd report #to read the generated output
```

I tested on a script and it's showing each called executable, with the same approach you may be able to follow even more events if you need more informations (all monitorable events are again show with `trace-cmd list`).

To show the executables in a nicer way, you can then grep for the results and take unique values (check if that works with your output, my version may be a little older).

```
trace-cmd report | grep -Eo "filename=[^ ]+" | sort | uniq
```

**NOTE**
As the manual says:

```
The trace-cmd(1) record command will set up the Ftrace Linux kernel tracer to record the specified plugins or events that happen while the command executes.
If no command is given, then it will record until the user hits Ctrl-C.
```

The tracer will show all events caught during the program execution, this means all processes executions will be logged, even if unrelated to the calling process. To be sure you are not getting some false-positives, try to have your system as light as possible while doing this.
You should be on the safe side with processes called by your process (even recursively), unless the main process dies or something weird happens in the meanwhile (it shouldn't really happen though).

Comment: Does this work recursively for all child processes as well?

Comment: In the test script I used, it's reporting also the calls of a second called script.
In the manual says _The trace-cmd(1) record command will set up the Ftrace Linux kernel tracer to record the specified plugins or events that happen while the command executes._, hence it should show you everything that gets executed in the lifespan of your program (even unrelated processes spawining in the system actually)

Comment: @glemco You should add the clarification from your comment to the answer by [edit]ing it.

Comment: I think I did it already, is it still unclear?

Answer (score 1):

> I first need to find out which programs are being used

You can enable process accounting. On Debian the package would be `acct`.

```
apt install acct      # Install the package
accton on             # Enable accounting to /var/log/account/pacct
```

Then you can view the commands executed

```
lastcomm              # All commands
lastcomm -u userid    # Processes executed by {userid}
```

As usual, `accton` and `lastcomm` have reference documentation (`man accton`, `man lastcomm` respectively).