# How do I log all commands executed by all users

Tags: command-line, bash, amazon-ec2, logs

I'd like to get the logs in the following format in one log line:

```
user_x executed command_y
```

I have found the following solutions:

- [How to log all Bash commands by all users on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93566/how-to-log-all-bash-commands-by-all-users-on-a-server/93570#93570)
- [How do I log all input and output in a terminal session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161935/how-do-i-log-all-input-and-output-in-a-terminal-session/858319#858319?newreg=48e124322d3444b18e1146474b1b0c41)

but here it is saving only the commands executed by the `root` user.

I have tried using audit rules as well, but the above solutions are more accurate regarding my use case.

Audit Rules save the logs in different lines with different types: `SYSCALL` (user info), `EXECVE` (executed command args), etc. Instead, I need this information in one log line.

I have followed these steps:

1. Edit `/etc/rsyslog.d/bash.conf`:

   ```
   vim /etc/rsyslog.d/bash.conf
   ```

   and add the following:

   ```
   local6.*    /var/log/commands.log
   ```
2. Open `/root/.bashrc`:

   ```
   vim /root/.bashrc
   ```

   and enter the following:

   ```bsh
   # Enable CLI Logging
   whoami="$(whoami)@$(echo $SSH_CONNECTION | awk '{print $1}')"export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$whoami [$$] $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" )"'
   ```
3. Restart `rsyslog` service:

   ```
   sudo service rsyslog restart
   ```

With the above, the logs are saved in `/var/log/commands.log` in the following format:

```
Aug 13 10:10:31 ip-172-31-3-192 ec2-user: root [19399] cat /var/log/commands.log
```

and the commands are saved only if I use `sudo su` (root). If I exit from `sudo su` and execute any command, then the commands don't get saved in `/var/log/commands.log`.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Possibly relevant - [Log which system executables have been used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/659001/100397) - but does not capture the command arguments, just the command itself

Comment: The most effective and unavoidable solution uses the kernel to record the commands. Auditd, for example

Answer (score 2):

Thank You Bob and https://askubuntu.com/questions/93566/how-to-log-all-bash-commands-by-all-users-on-a-server/93570#93570, I'm posting the steps that I followed from the above solution in my case (I am using Amazon Linux):

1. Edit `/etc/bashrc`:

   ```
   sudo -e /etc/bashrc
   ```

   and add this line:

   ```
   export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" )"'
   ```
2. Run the following to load the changes:

   ```
   source /etc/bashrc
   ```
3. Edit `/etc/rsyslog.d/bash.conf`:

   ```
   sudo -e /etc/rsyslog.d/bash.conf
   ```

   and add the following line:

   ```
   local6.*    /var/log/commands.log
   ```
4. Edit `/etc/logrotate.d/syslog`:

   ```
   sudo -e /etc/logrotate.d/syslog
   ```

   and add the following line:

   ```
   /var/log/commands.log
   ```
5. Restart `rsyslog` service:

   ```
   sudo service rsyslog restart
   ```

The result will be similar to the following, where you can see commands executed by root and the other user as well:

```
Aug 13 13:39:02 ip-172-31-3-192 ec2-user: root [23275]: rm logrotate.d/rsyslog  [0]
Aug 13 13:39:08 ip-172-31-3-192 ec2-user: root [23275]: cat logrotate.d/rsyslog  [1]
Aug 13 13:39:23 ip-172-31-3-192 ec2-user: root [23275]: sudo cat /var/log/commands.log  [0]
Aug 13 13:39:27 ip-172-31-3-192 ec2-user: root [23275]: sudo cat /var/log/commands.log  [0]
Aug 13 13:46:22 ip-172-31-3-192 ec2-user: ec2-user [17012]: sudo su [0]
Aug 13 13:46:54 ip-172-31-3-192 ec2-user: ec2-user [17012]: sudo /etc/rsyslog.d/bash.conf [1]
Aug 13 13:47:00 ip-172-31-3-192 ec2-user: ec2-user [17012]: sudo cat /etc/rsyslog.d/bash.conf [0]
Aug 13 13:47:10 ip-172-31-3-192 ec2-user: ec2-user [17012]: cat /etc/rsyslog.d/bash.conf [0]
```

Comment: "All _`bash`_ users _that do not redefine or clear `PROMPT_COMMAND`_ on a server"...

Comment: Or do `env PROMPT_COMMAND="" sudo do_bad_stuff`. Or, wrap evil commands in a script, or ... There are many ways of evading such surveillance. Or type lots of slightly different commands and fill up your logs. Or put a `logger` executable earlier in `$PATH`.